# cx_freeze setup script zip

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am using cx_Freeze with the following setup script:

```
exe = Executable(
    script="pyWindowAllignmentGUI.py",
    base="Win32GUI"
    )

setup(
    name = "pyWindowAllignmentGUI",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "An example wxPython script",
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

this works fine.
Now I try to compress all the libarys to a zip file using this setup script

```
build_exe_options={"compressed"}

exe = Executable(
    script="pyWindowAllignmentGUI.py",
    base="Win32GUI"
    )

setup(
    name = "pyWindowAllignmentGUI",
    version = "0.1",
    options = {"build_exe":build_exe_options},
    description = "An example wxPython script",
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

but i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    executables = [exe]
  File "d:\Program Files (x86)\Python3.2.3_64bit\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 365, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "d:\Program Files (x86)\Python3.2.3_64bit\lib\distutils\core.py", line 109, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "d:\Program Files (x86)\Python3.2.3_64bit\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 23, in __init__
    distutils.dist.Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
  File "d:\Program Files (x86)\Python3.2.3_64bit\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 233, in __init__
    for (opt, val) in cmd_options.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

i tried to use the "compressed" parameter according to this site:
http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils
but i seem to do something wrong ?
so how to use the compressed parameter right ?

**Update:**

I found out that thats the way to do it:

```
build_exe_options={"compressed":True}

exe = Executable(
    script="pyWindowAllignmentGUI.py",
    base="Win32GUI"
    )

setup(
    name = "pyWindowAllignmentGUI",
    version = "0.1",
    options = {"build_exe":build_exe_options},
    description = "An example wxPython script",
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

and further I found out, that the compressed paramter is True by default.

So as a result I have a library.zip in my build directory where all python-file are stored.
but still i have several .dlls and some .pyd file in my build folder.
(python32.dll,pythoncom32.dll,pywintypes32.dll,tcl85.dll,tk85.dll,unicodedata.pyd,win32api.pyd,win32gui.pyd,..)

is it possible to configure the setup script in a way they are also in a zip file ?

Comment: Yes, the options need to be a dictionary, not a set. No, cx_Freeze can't currently put your DLLs into a zip file, only the Python libraries.

Comment: See [Single file executables](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables) in the FAQ.